# How to set BMC authentication key for SCVMM host?

Tags: ipmi, scvmm, drac

I am trying to configure my hosts in SCVMM to use IPMI to allow shutting down and powering on from the SCVMM console.

The servers are Dell R710, and have iDRAC6 enterprise cards, running Server 2012R2.  SCVMM is 2012R2.

When I try to add the BMC in the host's properties, I get an error:

> Error (21257)
>
> A BMC authentication key is missing for <ipaddress>

The iDRAC has an encryption key set for IPMI.  I have the encryption key.  But I see nowhere to add it in SCVMM!

Googling that error message doesn't turn up any useful results.

Clearly on some level it knows it needs an authentication key, but there isn't anywhere to enter it.

Answer (score -1):

I changed it to SMASH instead of IPMI and that worked using my idrac credentials.